# Evaluate validity of fields based on action being performed in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms, validation

I have a complex Angular form representing a printable document. Form has two buttons to submit the form. One is for saving the working version and another to print the completed form to PDF.

The problem is simple, but more difficult to solve for me. Of course, when you are going to save a working version there will be unfilled fields. There are some allways required fields (such as name and personal ID) which are needed to save the form. Other fields are required only for printing. So the validity of these fields depends on the action (the button clicked by the user). I cannot determine the validity when the user is editing the field (angular validators are fired when fields content is changing), because I dont know which button will be clicked. I need to fire the validation of the whole form after one of the buttons was clicked. At that point I already know the action and can evaluate the validity of the fields (I have a custom angular validator to do this job).

My question is: how to trigger the (re)validation of the whole form from a function? If it is not possible, are there any other solutions to implement the validation described above?

I would prefer a solution where the $valid and $invalid properties of the fields are always set properly. My custom validator can ensure this. But how to trigger it on every field from a function? If it is not possible to trigger the validation by one function call, it is possible to iterate over all fields of the form? (to call the $validate() method of NgModelController)

Comment: Just kind of thinking out loud here, but could you use `ng-required` to conditionally set the required attribute on the various fields when saving vs. printing?

Comment: I cant use the build in validator based on the required attribute directly, because I need the perform additional actions in my custom validator. But it seems to be a good workaround. I need to verify it, but it looks like that changing the required attribute by `ng-required` will trigger the revalidation of the field. The question is: my custom validator will be triggered, too? I'm gonna try it. Thanks.